# VB .NET to C# Error: 'As' is not a member of 'Task(Of IFlurlResponse)'

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-conversion

I'm converting this C# line

```
return await _serviceUrl.WithOAuthBearerToken(bearerToken)
                                

.AppendPathSegment($"api/v1/accounts/{accountId}/identities/{identityId}")
                                .AllowAnyHttpStatus()
                                .PatchJsonAsync(model)
                                .As<Models.IdentityModel>();
```

To this line in VB .Net

```
Return Await _serviceUrl.WithOAuthBearerToken(bearerToken).AppendPathSegment($"api/v1/accounts/{accountId}/identities/{identityId}").AllowAnyHttpStatus().PatchJsonAsync(model).[As](Of Identity)()
```

But I got this error

> 'As' is not a member of 'Task(Of IFlurlResponse)'.

How do I fix it?

Thank in Advance

Comment: await it before you call As, if As is a member of IFlurlResponse e.g. not `A().B().CAsync().As()` because the Async returns a task, instead `(await A().B().CAsync()).As()`

Comment: like this?       
 `Dim bearerToken As String = Await _tokenService.GetAccessTokenAsync()
        Dim obj = Await _serviceUrl.WithOAuthBearerToken(bearerToken).AppendPathSegment($"api/v1/accounts/{accountId}/identities").AllowAnyHttpStatus().PostJsonAsync(model)
        Return obj`

Comment: Er.. not sure where the first Await (GetAccessTokenAsync) came from but if it's what you need to do.. Where's the As gone? And how come the call switched to Post from Patch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight translate would be:

```
Return (Await _serviceUrl.WithOAuthBearerToken(bearerToken) _
  .AppendPathSegment($"api/v1/accounts/{accountId}/identities/{identityId}") _ 
  .AllowAnyHttpStatus() _ 
  .PatchJsonAsync(model) _
).As(Of Identity)()
```

But I've just pulled out a project that uses Flurl and it doesn't seem to include `As` so I'm guessing that's some extension of something else..

Long story short, when you have a method name that ends in Async and returns an awaitable, Await it inside parentheses before you call more methods (on the parentheses) if you want to chain

```
Dim r = (Await(Await(Await x.AAsync()).BAsync()).CAsync()).D
```

Simplistically, if a `MethodAsync()` returns a `Task(Of X)` then calling `Await MethodAsync()` gives you the X, otherwise you're calling methods on the Task, not the X

---

Footnote:

While it's necessary to use square brackets in `[As]` to define a method called As, it's not necessary to have them to call it